# invalid blok type

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks

I am trying to create new custom child html and getting this error

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ongeldig bloktype: Mage_Page_Block_Template' in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Mage.php:595

Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ongeldig blokty...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('page/template', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/template', 'top_banner')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/template', 'top_banner')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

I add this to Page.XML

```
<block type="page/template" name="top_banner" template="page/template/topbanner.phtml"/>
```

And try to get child html with:

```
<div class="header-container-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="top_block">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top_banner') ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Can anyone give me some advice ?

Comment: <div class="header-container-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="top_block">
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top_banner') ?>
     <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div> I try to get child html in header

Comment: <block type="page/template" name="top_banner" template="page/template/topbanner.phtml"/> I Add this to Page xml

Comment: Does changing the block type to `type="core/template"` fix things?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure two things here.

1. Your block definition should be like this:

   ```
   <block type="core/template" name="top_banner" as="top_banner" template="page/template/topbanner.phtml"/>
   ```

   Magento provides a general block type `core/template` and hence you can use that. If you have lot of block logics within your block, then it is recommended to create a custom block for that. To do this, you need to know how can we create a custom module with a custom block.
   Also please note `as="top_banner"` section in the block defintion. This is the alias name of your block and it is what we need to use in `column*.phtml`
2. You should include this block inside `root` block.